# In Outlook what determines the name that appears below the subject line?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Sorry for not supplying a screenshot but I can't post a screenshot of my work email.

In Outlook though it shows something like:

> Subject Line of Email ((Timestamp))
>
> Person or Business Name

And the Person or Business Name is in a gray. What determines this, particularly for emails from new contacts or newsletters? Does it just parse the domain that the email came from or is there a way to configure this?

I am not actually interested in configuring this from Outlook, just want to know how Outlook determines it. We're trying to get our company newsletter to appear differently in client's emails if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In outlook it is "your name" and "email address"  You can set them to be whatever you want, just like the picture.  Your email will still reply back to your email address.

If you edit the "Your Name" and the "email address" field then they will display whatever you put in the boxes.  View the picture below.  I added President (name) to the your name field and barrack.obama@whitehouse.gove to the email address field.  These are obviously not my creds but they are accepted and sent.

[image]

Here is a link the full size pic.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwLC5.png

Comment: Thank you for the advice but please see the last paragraph of my question. I am not looking for how to set that on my end. I'm looking for how it determines it for incoming mail from other people.

Comment: by whatever they put in those fields. So if you want ppl to see your company name or whatever under the subject line that is where it goes.

Comment: Would a company that does our mailing lists for newsletters generally have that feature as well?

Comment: Most likely.  If you are using a third party company then they are most likey already doing something like this.

Comment: Thanks I'll have to contact them myself. If you edit your answer to include the info from your comments I'll be happy to mark it accepted. (I can't edit yet on SuperUser)